# Limit listagg function to first 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-concatenation, varchar2

I have a query that uses the `listagg` function to get all rows as a comma delimited string to ultimately be shipped to a big text box. I'm getting the following exception:

`ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

I know the problem is that the query being run to aggregate the data is returning so many rows that the string concatenation that `listagg` is doing violates the 4000 char limit. However, for my use case it's perfectly acceptable to truncate to the first 4000 characters.

How would I modify this example query from [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php) to limit the "value" column to be max 4000 characters?

`SELECT LISTAGG(product_name, ', ') WITHIN
 GROUP(
 ORDER BY product_name DESC) "Product_Listing"
  FROM products`

You can't wrap `substr` around the call `listagg' because`listagg`throws the exception before`substr` ever gets called.

I've seen a lot of question on SO about how to get around the 4000 character limit, but not to limit the resulting value.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### 12.2 and above

The `ON OVERFLOW` option makes is easy to handle more than 4000 bytes:

```
select listagg(product_name, ',' on overflow truncate) within group (order by product_name)
from products;
```

### 11.2 to 12.1

An analytic function can generate a running total length of the string aggregation.  Then an inline view can remove any values where the length is greater than 4000.

In a real query you may need to add a `partition by` to the analytic functions, to only count per some group.

```
--The first 4000 bytes of PRODUCT_NAME.
select
    --Save a little space for a ' ...' to imply that there is more data not shown.
    case when max(total_length) > 3996 then
        listagg(product_name, ', ') within group (order by product_name)||
            ' ...'
    else
        listagg(product_name, ', ') within group (order by product_name)
    end product_names
from
(
    --Get names and count lengths.
    select
        product_name,
        --Add 2 for delimiters. Use LENGTHB in case of multibyte characters.
        sum(lengthb(product_name) + 2) over (order by product_name) running_length,
        sum(lengthb(product_name) + 2) over () total_length
    from products
    order by product_name
)
where running_length <= 3996;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4648ef90377c49c3a4c4dcadcc57908c) demonstrating the query.

Comment: I have a database with special characters like "ç". I needed to use lengthb function instead length. I think it's because 4000 is a byte limit, not a character limit.

Comment: @ewerton I modified the query to work with any characters. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.