# The result of string concatenation is too long (LISTAGG)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm havin trouble while trying to execute this query because it says: "result of string concatenation is too long"

I'm using Oracle database

[image]

The SQL Query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        v.*
        ,min(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) min_cnt_org
        ,max(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) max_cnt_org
    from (
        select
          accountnumber
          ,org_id
          ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
          ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
          ,count(*)               over(partition by accountnumber,org_id) cnt_org
          ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs
        from mytable
        ) v
    ) v2
where cnt_distinct<>3
or min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org;
```

How can i make it run?

Comment: please take time and read how to ask database related questions.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the limit (by default) of a VARCHAR2 is 4000 characters (don't quote me). Are you trying to generate a longer string?

Comment: try this: listagg_clob: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/iuiyzdd8z4jquuca86yxq8s60. Or XMLAGG both functions return CLOB instead of VARCHAR2,  so there is no limit for output size.

Comment: Do you want all the values or do you only want the first 4000 characters? ibre5041 posted a solution for including all the values, and [here are techniques to only get the first 4000 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312991/409172)

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques